# Nav button visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide a navbar button, if the screen is larger than 991px (991 is because of bootstrap)

I can hide it with `visibility: hidden`, but when I'm trying to make it visible, it doesn't work.

```html
<div class="lathatosag">
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
        <span>Hirdetés kereső</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.lathatosag{
    visibility: hidden;
}

@media(max-width:991px){
    .lathatosag{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting to show on larger devices > 991px, then you need to change the media query to:

```
@media(min-width:992px){
    .lathatosag{
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```